# Cannot reproduce TransformedRegion example shown in documentation

Tags: plotting, bugs, regions

**Bug introduced in 10.0.2 or earlier and fixed in 11.1.0**

 Note: `TransformedRegion` was introduced in 10.0.0.

---

Reproducing an example from [Mathematica's help](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedRegion.html), I obtain an incomplete plot

```
ClearAll; a = TransformedRegion[Disk[{1, 1}, 4], {Indexed[#, 1] *Indexed[#, 2], 
Indexed[#, 1] + Indexed[#, 2]} &];RegionPlot[a]
```

[image]

instead of an entire plot. How to fix it?

Comment: "`ClearAll;`" doesn't do anything.  I've seen people using this more than once in the past week on this site, and I don't know where it is coming from.   You need to actually *call* the function, and give it an argument.  ``ClearAll["Global`*"]``.

Comment: @Szabolcs : Thank you. I will follow your advice.

Comment: It doesn't work in any of 10.0, 10.3.1, 10.4.1, 11.0.1.  Very strange.  I wonder if there is any version in which it works since this was introduced in 10.0 ... You should report this to Wolfram Support.  `DiscreteizeRegion` works fine.

Comment: @Szabolcs : I tried to submit it, but could not attach a *.nb file with the executed code. Because of this reason I asked the question.

Comment: Why not?  Did you try [here](http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=Feedback)?  If the web form doesn't work, use the email address: support at wolfram.com.

Comment: @Szabolcs : Yes, I did try to submit a report  here.

Comment: Doesn't work either in 10.1 and 10.2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure if others (or Wolfram Support) would agree, but this seems like a bug to me.  I'll leave tagging as [bugs](/questions/tagged/bugs) to others.  Please do report it to [Wolfram Support](http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/) though.

I get the same result that you show in all of 10.0.2, 10.3.1, 10.4.1 and 11.0.1.  This is surprising because the functionality was introduced in 10.0, so I wonder if there is any released version at all in which this works correctly.

Luckily the workaround is easy.  Just set the `PlotRange` manually.  The correct value can be determined using [`RegionBounds`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionBounds.html).  This is another reason why it feels suspiciously like a bug that this is not done automatically with `PlotRange` set to `Full`, `All` or `Automatic`.

```
RegionPlot[a, PlotRange -> RegionBounds[a], 
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]]
```

[image]

I used `PlotRangePadding` simply to leave some extra space around the edges.

An alternative is using [`DiscretizeRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretizeRegion.html).

```
DiscretizeRegion[a]

DiscretizeRegion::drc: Available methods not able to resolve all components of dimension less than the embedding dimension 2; these may be omitted from the result.
```

[image]

I'm not exactly sure what the message is about as this seems like a simple 2D region to me.

Comment: A trace shows that `RegionPlot` is calling `RegionBounds` with the `"Finite"` range type. This happens inside ``Graphics`Region`RegionDump`getBBoxFromRegion``

Comment: I'm not sure if the bug is that "Minimal" should be used instead, or if "Finite" should do a better job of finding an interesting region.

Comment: @SimonWoods The reason why I went ahead and added the bug header was this post: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/130744/12  It wasn't 100% clear to me if this was really a bug or if we're just expecting too much.

Comment: The documentation examples were fixed in 11.1.0 by replace RegionPlot with the new Region object.  Unfortunately, RegionPlot hasn't gotten better at picking a sensible PlotRange.