# RegionPlot of TransformedRegion still broken in Mathematica 11?

Tags: regions, coordinate-transformation, version-11

[This question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72666/transformedregion-regionplot-broken-in-10-0-2-0) confirms that `RegionPlot` of a `TransformedRegion` is broken in version 10. One year later, is this problem still unfixed in version 11, or is there something wrong with my Mathematica?

From `TransformedRegion` documentation:

```
\[ScriptCapitalR]=TransformedRegion[Disk[{1,1},4],{Indexed[#,1] Indexed[#,2],Indexed[#,1]+Indexed[#,2]}&];
RegionPlot[\[ScriptCapitalR]]
```

Picture before evaluation, in documentation:

[image]

Picture after evaluating:

[image]

Using version 11.0.1.0

Comment: still broken for me in 11.0.1

Comment: Still broken in the prerelease version of 11.1.0